# Can't include Language switch in Nav Menu

Tags: menus, navigation, plugin-qtranslate

I am trying to add to my menu bar some language elements. I'm using the qTranslate plugin and I would like to add the language switch to the menu bar.

My them is calling in the *header.php*

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu'));?>
```

And then I added to my *functions.php* the following code, which remains without effect :

```
function qtrans_generateLanguageListCode($id='') {
    global $q_config;
    if(is_404()) $url = get_option('home'); else $url = '';
    if($id=='') $id = 'qtranslate';
    $id .= '-chooser';
    foreach(qtrans_getSortedLanguages() as $language) {
        $classes = array('lang-'.$language);
        if($language == $q_config['language'])
            $classes[] = 'active';
        echo '<li class="'. implode(' ', $classes) .'"><a href="'.qtrans_convertURL($url, $language).'"';
        // set hreflang
        echo ' hreflang="'.$language.'" title="'.$q_config['language_name'][$language].'"';
        echo ' class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_'.$language.'"';
        echo '><span';
        echo ' style="display:none"';
        echo '>'.$q_config['language_name'][$language].'</span></a></li>';
    }
}

function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    $translinks = qtrans_generateLanguageListCode();
    $items = $items . $translinks;
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Could anyone help me to understand what I am missing ? I have to add that I am using a child theme of Twenty Twelve, but this should be without effect.

Thanks !

Comment: You are `echo`-ing in your qTrans function, while you have to `return` the data.

Comment: Whats the tag for the switch?

Comment: @tf you are fully right, returning is much better ! Nevertheless, it is not still not returning anything... The nav bar stays empty... :-/ And I don't have reputation enough to even vote you up... normally on StackOverflow :-p

Comment: @BradDalton the switch is the <li> construct I am doing in the previous function

Comment: http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3&p=16#p16

Comment: Thanks @BradDalton but this is not the answer. I am able to integrate that, but I don't want it in the sidebar or as a separate list. This is why I am constructing the <li> elements and willing to add them to the navigation menu, but it is somehow not working...

Comment: That's exactly what i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `return` the data in the qtrans function:

```
function qtrans_generateLanguageListCode($id='') {
    global $q_config;
    if (is_404()) $url = get_option('home'); else $url = '';
    if ('' === $id) $id = 'qtranslate';
    $id .= '-chooser';
    $output = '';
    foreach (qtrans_getSortedLanguages() as $language) {
        $classes = array('lang-'.$language);
        if($language == $q_config['language'])
            $classes[] = 'active';
        $output .= '<li class="'. implode(' ', $classes) .'"><a href="'.qtrans_convertURL($url, $language).'"';
        // set hreflang
        $output .= ' hreflang="'.$language.'" title="'.$q_config['language_name'][$language].'"';
        $output .= ' class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_'.$language.'"';
        $output .= '><span';
        $output .= ' style="display:none"';
        $output .= '>'.$q_config['language_name'][$language].'</span></a></li>';
    }
    return $output;
}

function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    $translinks = qtrans_generateLanguageListCode();
    $items = $items . $translinks;
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Comment: OK sorry @tf, this works ! I just needed to check the box to make it the Primary Menu !!! A pity I can't vote you up